# Application calls old source functions

Tags: c, linux, file

There is an application on remote machine with Linux OS(Fedora), writing to the log file when certain events occur. Some time ago I changed format of the message being written to the log file. But recently it turned out that for some reason in some seldom cases log files with old format messages appear there. I know for sure that none part of my code can write such strings. Also there is no instance of the old application running. Does anyone have some ideas why it can happen? It's not possible to check which process writes those files because anything like auditctl is not installed there, and neither package manager or yum to get it or install. Application is written in C language.

Comment: What has happened is that one of the things you claim to be true arn't true. Either your app still has a few places with the old message format (or you didn't recompile all the source code files that got changed when you altered the format), or there's an old instance of the application running. (You might also not need auditctl to see who has the log file open, you can just run `ls -l /proc/*/name_of_log_file`)

Comment: This message was written only from one place it's just a few lines of code. And in 95% cases it writes new message. And the application doesnt keep a file open. Each time a new file with unique name is created.

Comment: "*This message was written only from one place ...*" then explicitly remove this code, perhaps by commenting it out,  and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fuser command to find out all the processes that are using that file

```
`fuser file.log`
```